# Wrapped Ether balance disappears from wallet on Etherscan by conversion?

Tags: erc-20, etherscan, privacy, swaps, wrapped-tokens

The following wallet on Etherscan shows 3 transactions of Wrapped Ether (WETH) being transferred in under the ERC-20 transactions tab, a large amount, but not how they are transferred out, assuming that the wallet owner did move the funds out

- https://etherscan.io/address/0x77f0decba8a2200c49ba5b1c2fc5d85d0c608e2d#tokentxns

How were they able to move the WETH out of the wallet without it appearing in Etherscan? Might they have converted the funds using a DeFi swap platform to a stablecoin or Monero or something that was untraceable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They were not transfered out.

Those 3 transactions summ up to : `19.62795` WETH.

You can go on the [WETH contract page](https://etherscan.io/token/0xc02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc2?a=0x77f0decba8a2200c49ba5b1c2fc5d85d0c608e2d#readContract) and read the balance of the address refered to by your transactions : `0x77F0DECBa8a2200c49BA5B1c2Fc5D85D0C608e2d`.

The output is : `19627950000000000000` which divided by `10^decimals` equals : `19.62795`

No transactions is showing an approve or transfer call, because there was none. The address is still the owner of all the WETH received.

Comment: Is there a way for them to move the WETH out of the wallet without it appearing in Etherscan? Might they convert the funds using a DeFi swap platform to a stablecoin or Monero or something that is untraceable, resulting in the BalanceOf changing to 0 wei?

Comment: They would need to either `approve` a spender, or `transfer` the funds themselves. Either way, those require a tx to be sent, so it will be visible on etherscan.

Comment: So there's no way to empty funds or tokens from an Eth wallet inconspicuously whatsoever? Everything is traceable?

Comment: No, a state change has to be approved by the network, so it has to be visible on the network.

Comment: If the WETH is moved to a centralized exchange wallet, which is clumped together in wallet aggregators that Etherscan calls "Coinbase 6" and "Kraken 4", the user can still be doxed?

Comment: I don't know how funds are managed on those. All I can tell you for sure is that when the user transfers from his / her personal wallet this is a blockchain state change and it must be public.

Comment: Would an ether tumbler be able to obfuscate the outflow of funds, in that, when the WETH, after being converted to ETH, is placed in the tumbler, it splits into several separate constituent amounts, that can re-group at a target wallet sent to without being traced to the origin WETH wallet?

Comment: Yes, it seems that you are refering to something like tornado cash : https://tornado.cash/ this is exactly what they do by relying on Zk-SNARKS.